# WebScraping - BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the medium website. Here is my code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

class Publication:
    def __init__(self, publication):
        self.publication = publication
        self.headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}# mimics a browser's request
    def get_articles(self):
        "Get the articles of the user/publication which was given as input"
        publication = self.publication
        r = requests.get(f"https://{publication}.com/", headers=self.headers)
        soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml')
        elements = soup.find_all('h2')
        for x in elements:
            print(x.text)

publication = Publication('towardsdatascience')
publication.get_articles()
```

It is working somewhat good but it is not scraping all the titles. It is only getting the some of the articles from the top of the page. I want it to get all the article names from the page. It also getting the side bar stuff like who to follow and all. I dont want that. How do I do that?

Here is the output of my code:

```
How to Rewrite and Optimize Your SQL Queries to Pandas in 5 Simple Examples
Storytelling with Charts
Simplify Your Data Preparation with These Four Lesser-Known Scikit-Learn Classes
Non-Parametric Tests for Beginners (Part 1: Rank and Sign Tests)
BigQuery Best Practices: Unleash the Full Potential of Your Data Warehouse
How to Test Your Python Code with Pytest
7 Signs You’ve Become an Advanced Sklearn User Without Even Realizing It
How Data Scientists Save Time
MLOps: What is Operational Tempo?
Finding Your Dream Master’s Program in AI
Editors
TDS Editors
Ben Huberman
Caitlin Kindig
Sign up for The Variable
```

Comment: Content you're looking for is hydrated in page via JS calls to some GraphQL endpoints. You can scrape those endpoints (complex -- you need to construct correct, big payloads), or you can use Selenium (less complex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Barry the Platipus mentions in a comment, the content you want is loaded via Javascript. A complicating factor is that this content is only loaded when you scroll the page, so even a naive Selenium-based solution like this will still return only the same set of results as your existing code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)


class Publication:
    def __init__(self, publication):
        self.publication = publication

    def get_articles(self):
        "Get the articles of the user/publication which was given as input"
        publication = self.publication
        driver.get(f"https://{publication}.com/")
        elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2")
        for x in elements:
            print(x.text)


publication = Publication("towardsdatascience")
publication.get_articles()
```

To get more than the initial set of articles, we need to scroll the page. For example, if we add a simple loop to scroll the page a few times before querying for `h2` elements, like this:

```
    def get_articles(self):
        "Get the articles of the user/publication which was given as input"
        publication = self.publication
        driver.get(f"https://{publication}.com/")
        for x in range(3):
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

            # The sleep here is to give the page time to respond.
            time.sleep(0.2)
        elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h2")
        for x in elements:
            print(x.text)
```

Then the output of the code is:

```
Large Language Models in Molecular Biology
How to Rewrite and Optimize Your SQL Queries to Pandas in 5 Simple Examples
Storytelling with Charts
Simplify Your Data Preparation with These Four Lesser-Known Scikit-Learn Classes
Non-Parametric Tests for Beginners (Part 1: Rank and Sign Tests)
BigQuery Best Practices: Unleash the Full Potential of Your Data Warehouse
How to Test Your Python Code with Pytest
7 Signs You’ve Become an Advanced Sklearn User Without Even Realizing It
How Data Scientists Save Time
MLOps: What is Operational Tempo?
Finding Your Dream Master’s Program in AI
Temporary Variables in Python: Readability versus Performance
Naive Bayes Classification
Predicting the Functionality of Water Pumps with XGBoost
Detection of Credit Card Fraud with an Autoencoder
4 Reasons Why I Won’t Sign the “Existential Risk” New Statement
The Data-centric AI Concepts in Segment Anything
3D Deep Learning Python Tutorial: PointNet Data Preparation
Why Trust and Safety in Enterprise AI Is (Relatively) Easy
The Principles of a Modern Computer Scientist
```

That page appears to be an "infinite scroll" style of page, so you probably want to set a limit on how many times you scroll to find new content.

Comment: Page can be scrolled as long as new information is being added to it, in `while` loop, for example, and then break out of it. +1.

Comment: So like `while true:` instead of `for x in range(3):`?

Comment: Also How do I get rid of useless gibberish that is getting printed before the article names getting pritnted?

Comment: I don't see any "useless gibberish" in the output here; can you be more explicit about what you see?

Comment: `DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:56974/devtools/browser/c03cf376-fe23-4c62-af54-35e0a0c75346
[0602/193134.733:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "      ...
  .,ok000Oxc.     'oxo,  .'
 ,kWMMMMMMMMXo;. ;KMWMX: lK,
,0MMMMMMMMMMMWNd'xMMMMMO;xWl
lWMMMMMMMMMMMMM0lOMMMMMKoOMo
cNMMMMMMMMMMMMMk:OMMMMM0lkWl
.dNMMMMMMMMMMKx; lWMMMWd.dN:
  ;kXWMMMMWKd'   .oXWXx. ;o.
    .;ccc:,.       .,.
", source: https://cdn-client.medium.com/lite/static/js/main.1f67da2f.js (2)
[0602/193134.734:INFO:CONSOLE(2)] "We're hiring! https://medium.com/jobs-at-medium/work-at-medium-959d1a85284e", source: https://cdn-client.med`

Comment: I have no idea what's generating that in your environment. I don't know what "devtools" is, but when I run the code in this answer from the command line, there is no extraneous output. The output I show in the answer is the only output generated by the code.

Comment: oh well! If you know do let me know!

Comment: By the way what barry the platipus told about while loop how do i incorporate it in the code?

Comment: You'll find several examples of that online, e.g., https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/using-python-and-selenium-to-scrape-infinite-scroll-web-pages-825d12c24ec7

Comment: `[0602/213749.345:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "The resource https://miro.medium.com/v2/resize:fit:2569/1*Pxg5mSUxMauqJj07YJmtdg.png was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate 'as' value and it is preloaded intentionally.", source: https://towardsdatascience.com/ (0)` is the error/msg Im getting